# What lets you the free Phonegap-build account?

Tags: phonegap-build

In docs indicated: `Creative Cloud free membership — 1 private app, unlimited public apps`.

Could you please make more clear:

- What means 'public apps'? Is that means that the project should be hosted on Github? Which limitations will be applied in this case? (I'm not a Github user yet).
- Does 'one private app' means that I will be able to unpload zip-file only once? Or I will be able to make changes to this application?

Answer (score 0):

I've get an answer from the Adobe support stating that:

- Free account lets me to make updates to the single private application any time I'd want.
- Public applications will be accessible by anyone via public Github account (no any other limitations stated).

The citation:

> Private apps are apps hosted on a private git repo or by submitting a
>   zipped folder or your project.
>
> It cannot be accessed by anyone other than you, admin and contributors
>   you added when creating the project.
>
> You can edit and make changes to this app at any time and use the
>   update button to submit the changes.
>
> Public apps on the other hand can be viewed by anyone provided they
>   know the app id.
>
> The app must be hosted on a public github account who's code can be
>   accessed by anyone.
>
> You can also make changes to this at any time you want.